# show more code not working properly in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using code for show more/show less for long paragraphs in HTML and CSS for my page.

The code works properly.(All the code will be displayed below). 
But when the text is inside a `<p>` tag, it doesn't work. When I click show more, the full text disappears.

If I remove the `<p>` tag, the show more function works correctly.

Eg:

```
<div class="moreless">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
     </p>
     <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>
</div>
```

If I write the above text without the `<p>` tag it works.

Have I missed some code?

This is the code I used:

HTML:

```
<div class="moreless">
  <p>Lorem ipsum.....
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    color: #777777;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
    line-height: 45px
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 300;  
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more";
    var lesstext = "Show less";


   $('.moreless').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+     '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you probably want to name your variables differently. `moreless` can be tough to read for you and others. try camelCase `moreLess`, snake_case `more_less`, or kabob-case `more-less`.

Comment: The functions are interacting with the element who's class is moreless, the div is .moreless not the p tag, try updating $('.moreless') to $('.moreless p'), or move the moreless class to the p tags.

Comment: Where is `.morelink` in the html. Can you share that part of the code?

Comment: @MCMXCII moving the moreless does work. But Mamdouh has given a better answer which also helps me. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @Goose Good suggestion. The code for morelink is in the CSS part. It is not written in the html.

Comment: @BonzyJC How could `$(".morelink").click(function(){` work if `.morelink` doesn't exist in the html?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to get `.text()` - not `.html()` - then get `.substring(0,300)` and use `.toggleClass()` with paragraphs to hide or display.

See this example

```js
var showChar = 300;
var moretext = "Show more";
var lesstext = "Show less";

$(".moreless").each(function() {
  var ellipsestext = $(this).text() <= showChar ? "" : "...";
  //append shrinked text
  $(this).append("<p class='shrink'>" + $(this).text().substring($(this).text().indexOf("\n") + 2, showChar).replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") + ellipsestext + "</p>");
  //append readmore button
  $(this).append('<a href="#" class="moreellipses">' + moretext + '</a>');
  //control visibility by class names
  $(this).find(".shrink").addClass("dsp");
  $(this).children().not(".shrink, .moreellipses").addClass("hdn");
});



$(".moreellipses").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".moreless").find(".shrink").toggleClass("hdn");
  $(this).closest(".moreless").children().not(".shrink, .moreellipses").toggleClass("hdn");
  $(this).text($(this).text() == moretext ? lesstext : moretext);
  return false;
})
```

```css
.dsp {
  display: block;
}
.hdn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moreless">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Switch the `show more` and `show less` text around.

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly. Thank you @Mamdouh.

Comment: In case I need to add other tags such as <br>, what should I do?
I tried adding a <br>, but it won't recognize it until I press show more.
That is, the <br> was before the 300th character, after which rest of the text will be hidden.
For example, 
<div class="moreless">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<br>
<p> consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>

Comment: You want to let <br/> in shorten block.

Comment: Yes. The <br> will be in the shortened block. So there will be a break in the lines visible also in the shortened block.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelance I just realised that the br thing still didn't work. The break I saw was coming from the <p>. So the updated code didn't work for <br> in the shortened content. 
     `<div class= "moreless">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolo</p>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <p>sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
    </div>`  
For the above case, I was not able to see the effect of the 4 <br>.

Comment: use <p></p> instead of <br/>